# Message: element not interactable

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to input a string into a text field on a website and it is giving me an error.

I tried getting the exact element and also it's parent. With each one, I tried locating them with XPath, id, and name, without success.

This are some of the examples I tried.

```html
<td><input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" required="" id="id_username" maxlength="254">
<div class="formvalidate_spinner formvalidate_hidden" id="username_spinner">
<img src="/static/formvalidateassets/spinner.gif">
</div>
</td>
```

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').send_keys("username").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_username"]').send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys("username")
```

I expect to insert a given username into the input field, but whatever I try, the error given is selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Make sure you wait until the element is present, using WebDriverWait. And also check if the element is present in an iframe.

Comment: I used the element_to_be_clickable now and there's no iframe, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable` and insert `username`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'id_username'))).send_keys('username')
```

You need to imports following to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It still doesn't input anything with this, I'm so lost why doesn't it work, because I did this with many sites, but this one just doesn't want to work. It's not iframe either.

Comment: can you share your url?